# How to always show alert of my Cocoa application pop up all other applications?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I create the app simple. the app just remind work. I have problem how to my Alert always show pop up all other app. I tried code but my alert will hide when use other app I want my alert look like this alert in image
I tried code

[image]

```
let myPopup: NSAlert = NSAlert()
    myPopup.messageText = "Notification"
    myPopup.informativeText = "Hello world"
    myPopup.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.WarningAlertStyle
    myPopup.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    myPopup.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    myPopup.runModal()
```

But when I use other app it hide.
I want always show alert.
You can tutorial code example help me ?

I just beginner. I want writer app remind simple. I spent a whole day to do it but i can't. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the windowLevel property of your alerts `window` object. `NSModalPanelWindowLevel` should give the desired effect.